I'm working with react js and electron using webpack. I try to install MUI but it's give me an error when I use MUI component
Follwoing is the error that shown:
WARNING in ./node_modules/@mui/base/useSelect/useSelect.js 57:24-48
export 'defaultOptionStringifier' (imported as 'defaultOptionStringifier') was not found in './defaultOptionStringifier' (possible exports: default)

Do I need to do some config on webpack rules?
Following is my webpack rules:
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    // We're specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
    // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
    test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'images',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  // Put your webpack loader rules in this array.  This is where you would put
  // your ts-loader configuration for instance:
  /**
   * Typescript Example:
   *
   * {
   *   test: /\.tsx?$/,
   *   exclude: /(node_modules|.webpack)/,
   *   loaders: [{
   *     loader: 'ts-loader',
   *     options: {
   *       transpileOnly: true
   *     }
   *   }]
   * }
   */
];

